# Azure Cloud Shell ssh keys persistence

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

I am using Azure Cloud Shell to ssh into my VMs.

I have created SSH keys, created my VMs and was able to ssh into my VMs.
My Bash cloud shell session was suddenly disconnected (not the main issue) and after opening a new session to Cloud shell again I was not able to ssh into my VM anymore. I checked my .ssh dir and non of my keys were there anymore (empty).

I know the dir clouddrive is persisted but I want to confirm if .ssh is.

If not what is the way to achieve this so I do not run into this issue again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `.ssh` directory is not a persistent directory. As you know, only the directory `clouddrrive` can persist your files. So the possible solution is that you can store your SSH key in the `clouddrive`, when you use a new session, you can copy the `.ssh` from the `clouddrive`. Or add the parameter `-i` then the command looks like this:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private_key username@IP
```